# comparing int and char in c ,using if condition

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, char, c99

```
 char  c[50];
scanf("%s",c);
int counter;
for(int i=0;i<strlen(c);i++){
    for(int j=0;j<=9;j++){
        if(j==c[i]) // this line not comparing 
        counter+=1;
    }
```

Comparing integer (j) to digit in array c, while debugging it is not comparing

Answer (score 3):

You need to compare codes of characters that represent digits. It can be done for example the following way

```
if ( j + '0' == c[i] )
```

Pay attention to that the variable count in your code snippet is not initialized.

```
int counter;
```

You need to initialize it

```
int counter = 0;
```

Another approach to write the loop as pointed to by `@pmg` is the following

```
for( char j = '0'; j <= '9'; j++ ){
```

Also instead of the inner loop you could use the standard C function `isdigit`.

```
if ( isdigit( ( unsigned char )c[i] ) ) ++count;
```

Comment: works thanks , but why did you use quotes in  j + '0' . how does it work

Comment: @RajaSekharReddyEvuri You are comparing characters of the string c. So you need to compare them also with characters. Character '1' is evaluated like '0' + 1. For example in ASCII the code of the character '0' is 48 while the code of the character '1' is 49, the code of the character '2' is 50 and so on.